# Flutter Firebase get documents by array of IDs

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How would I get a Query of documents from a collection using a list of IDs? Let's says I have the following:

```
List<String> someList = ['abc123', 'def456', 'hij789']; // Need to query for these documentIDs
```

I would normally do the following. But this obviously won't work since I need to query the documentIDs.

```
Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection(APIPath.products())
        .where('someField', whereIn: someList);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [FieldPath.documentId()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html).

```
Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection(APIPath.products())
        .where(FieldPath.documentId(), whereIn: someList);
```

Note that you are limited to 10 items in the list, and this might actually be slower than just requesting each document individually with `get()`.

Comment: This is great thanks! Just curious to know how I would use get() with multiple queries and return a stream. The limit 10 is a bit concerning lol.

Comment: I don't know - I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: any solution to requesting them individually? I am currently trying to do exactly that. I have user which contains a list of playlistIds, and trying to load all the users playlists content asynchronously on start