# Flutter/Firebase get documents by list of IDs using .get()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is a followup to [Flutter Firebase get documents by array of IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824167/flutter-firebase-get-documents-by-array-of-ids/60824186#60824186).

How would I get a Query of documents from a collection using a list of IDs? Let's says I have the following:

```
List<String> someList = ['abc123', 'def456', 'hij789']; // Need to query for these documentIDs
```

I'm using `FieldPath.documentId()` which works, but limits the query to 10.

```
Query query = Firestore.instance
    .collection(APIPath.products())
    .where(FieldPath.documentId(), whereIn: someList);
```

I would normally pass `query` to a function of mine that would return a `Stream<List<Product>>` as seen below.

```
return _service.queryStream(
  query: query,
  path: APIPath.products(),
  builder: (data) => Product.fromMap(data),
);
```

I know `get()` is a better option, but not sure what the code would look like if I wanted to return a `Stream<List<Product>>`.