# How do i modify the code to have a Stream<dynamic> type stream for stream builder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Inside Stream builder, it is asking me to put `Stream<builder>` otherwise throwing an error,

`type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>'`

Now since I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63217091/13146732), i had to code the stream something like this,

```
getGroupsOfUser() async {
    String _userID = await _getUID();
    DocumentSnapshot userInfo = await userCollection.document(_userID).get();
    return groupCollection.where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: userInfo.data['groups']).snapshots();
  }
```

Now I know maybe if I could overcome using async I may fix it but I need to get the uid and the array of groups which is an async function and I can't really assign them as variables otherwise I'm getting the error `only static members can be accessed in initializers`

Please, someone, help me I am very beginner in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getGroupsOfUser()` should return a `Stream` since `snapshots()` returns a `Stream`. Therefore you need to do the following:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getGroupsOfUser() async* {
    String _userID = await _getUID();
    DocumentSnapshot userInfo = await userCollection.document(_userID).get();
    yield* groupCollection.where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: userInfo.data['groups']).snapshots();
  }
```

Since you need to return a stream then you need to use `async*` and use the `yield*` keyword to return.

Answer (score 1):

The error must be from the line

```
return groupCollection.where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: userInfo.data['groups']).snapshots();
```

Because .snapshots() method returns a Stream instead of a Future, and since your getGroupsOfUser() is a Future, it is throwing an error that you cannot return a Stream from a function that returns a Future.

My solution:
1 - Put the logic for getting the userID and the userInfo inside the initState() i.e make a Future for it.
2 - Seperate the last line from the Future and wrap it with a StreamBuilder after successfully getting the userinfo from step 1.